# Crysis 2: Pinger battle?

Tags: ps3, crysis-2

Once I get to the Pinger battle on the mission "Corporate Collapse" In Crysis 2 and I start battling it everything seems fine but when I beat the Pinger the next objective is to Regroup with Chino at vehicles. I go to Chino but he does absolutely nothing. He doesn't talk, move, react when I run him over with his own humvee or anything! Has anyone found a way to fix this? I've replayed the entire level at least 8 times and it is getting me no where.

Answer (score 3):

So a Google search showed that many have faced the problem and it seems that Crytek hasn't released a patch fixing it.

One method is to start from the previous mission. The one before corporate collapse. Don't load a saved game, go to New Game > Mission Select.

[After pinger battle](https://secure.mycrysis.com/forums/topic12835)

Comment: Ok but is it just that simple? Do you know if it works on the first time or if it might fail and I'll have to do it again? I just want to be sure.

Comment: Nope I don't think it is that simple . If it doesn't work in the first try IMO you should download a save file which has the next mission/completed game .

Comment: Thank you so much GTX!! It worked. Thank you Thank you Thank you.

Comment: I am happy it worked . ^_^ .